# getting Highcharts to redraw

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a form that will allow me to edit parts of my chart.  One of them is the subtitle but for some reason the chart.redraw() isn't working and I'm not getting an error message back.  The chart needs to redraw once the input field has changed.  The chart already updates with a redraw every minute so I know it works otherwise but for some reason in this single function it won't call redraw().  This is very important because another option is to hide/show the legend and that will need a redraw().

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Sub Title" data-chart="chart_3972002" data-action="chartSub">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('input[data-action="chartSub"]').change(function(){           
    $('.unSaved').html('Saving').css('color','#669900').delay(800).fadeOut();
    var key = $(this).data('chart');
    var chart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    chart.subTitle = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(chart));

    var Chart = $('#'+key).highcharts();
    Chart.setTitle(null, {text: chart.subTitle});
    Chart.redraw();
});
```

Comment: ok - for some reason when I switch from Chart.redraw() to Chart.render() it works but I don't find documentation in the API Reference for render().  Just found a reference to it in someone else's question that seemed similar.

Answer (score 0):

Set title function redraws chart automatically, so you don't need to use redraw() function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle()

Comment: setTitle doesn't redraw chart - it only add/changes/removes title and subtitle.  If I add a subtitle there is overlap until the next scheduled chart update that redraws the chart.

Comment: Did you open related examples which introduce different solution ?